# Returning object based on input type

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement a Scala function similar to `userFor` as shown in the code snippet below, where the return type of the function is dependent on the type of the input parameter. In this example, the Scala compiler reports "Expression of type `System1User.type` doesn't conform to expected type `SystemUser[S]`".

Is there a way to create a factory method such as `userFor` that will use the compile time type of the input to return the correct output type?

```
sealed trait System {
  def name: String
}
case object System1 extends System { def name = "1" }
case object System2 extends System { def name = "2" }

sealed trait SystemUser[S <: System] {
  def use(s: S): String
}
object System1User extends SystemUser[System1.type] {
  override def use(s: System1.type) = s"${s.name} is in use"
}
object System2User extends SystemUser[System2.type] {
  override def use(s: System2.type) = s"${s.name} is in use"
}

object SystemUser {
  //TODO: how to make the types work out here?
  def userFor[S <: System](sys: S): SystemUser[S] = {
    sys match {
      case System1 => System1User
      case System2 => System2User
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Is this answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that in my case, it was sufficient to just do:

```
object SystemUser {

  def userFor(sys: System1.type): SystemUser[System1.type] = {
    sys match {
      case System1 => System1User
    }
  }

  def userFor(sys: System2.type): SystemUser[System2.type] = {
    sys match {
      case System2 => System2User
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Obviously, the real world use case is more complicated than this - there are actually multiple things that use System1 and System2, so the factory functions `userFor` take multiple parameters, but the dispatch is based on the type of the first argument, which lets me specify the return type, and the caller uses the function in the way that I'd hoped to achieve anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is the fact that you promised to return a `SystemUser[S]` from `userFor`, where `S` is some subtype of `System`. But you cannot keep that promise. You are not returning `SystemUser[S]`; you are returning either `SystemUser[System1.type]` or `SystemUser[System2.type]`. What would happen if `S` is something other than one of those two types? What if someone invoked `userFor` parameterized with `SomeNewSystemSubtype` (let's say that it's a valid subtype of `System`)?

You can remove the dependency to type `S` and simply return "some subtype of `System`":

```
def userFor[S <: System](sys: S): SystemUser[_ <: System] = {
```

Cleaner solution would be to make `SystemUser` covariant in its type parameter because then `SystemUser[System1.type]` would be a subclass of `SystemUser[System]`, which means you would be able to do this:

```
sealed trait SystemUser[+S <: System] {
  def use(s: S): String
}
...
def userFor[S <: System](sys: S): SystemUser[System] = {
```

But unfortunately your method `def use(s: S): String` has a parameter of type `S`, and that's a contravariant position. I'm not sure if you are familiar with this stuff, but taking care of that is not easy - you would need to modify your method into something like def `use[T >: S](s: T): String` which would require changes in implementations (since now any type above `S` can appear as a parameter) and in your case this is probably not worth it.

Comment: I'm playing around with this a bit. In my real world codebase, I do have the power to change nearly all of these traits and classes. Switching the return type to `SystemUser[_ <: System]` lets the code compile, but it renders the returned objects useless, because `SystemUser.userFor(System1).use(System1)` doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right; compiler doesn't know what's the underlying type. I don't think you can solve this with just one userFor method because it returns two objects of different types, and you must lose some type information. You cannot say "return type is either of type A or B", you can only say "return type is of type C, which is a superclass of A and B" but in that case, as you witnessed yourself, you lose information on whether it's actually A or B underneath.

Comment: Yeah. But thanks for your help. I'm going to approve my own answer below, but I wouldn't have quite gotten there without tinkering with your answers!

Comment: Glad I could help!